# Why are actual parameters called "arguments"?

Tags: programming-languages, terminology

Where does the word "argument" (in the programming sense) come from?
i.e. Why are actual parameters called "arguments"?

The meanings don't seem related, and I haven't found any explanation of it anywhere.

---

**Note** on the terminology:

- "Formal" parameters (also known simply as "parameters") are the "placeholder" names (say, `x`) -- the *declared* parameters of a function.
- "Actual" parameters (also known as "arguments") are the *actual values* which are *passed* to a function (say, `5`), hence I used this term above to prevent any confusion.

Comment: parameters means the declaration, arguments then values used.

Comment: It comes from math. Obviously, the next question is "so where did the term originate in math?"

Comment: This question is being discussed [here](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/5524/1204).

Comment: Just a note regarding the edit, I put the word "actual" in there to distinguish them from "formal" parameters. Otherwise there are going to be a million people thinking I didn't understand the difference, who will try to answer the wrong question.

Comment: @Mehrdad Oh I'm sorry, I didn't realize that. Can you [edit] your question to re-add that, and perhaps even include a short code sample illustrating which you are referring to? The two are often confused, and honestly I've never thought twice about the fact parameters are different than arguments until I read [this question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/19416/1130) today.

Comment: @Rachel: Yeah sure, no worries, I'll add it.

Comment: I think a better question would be: *Why are arguments called "actual parameters"?* This formal/actual parameter business seems to have been made up by someone who didn't know that the name for "actual parameter" is *argument*.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The term was adopted by computer scientists when they applied mathematical reasoning to programming in the mid 20th century.

The word *argument* has the general sense of **something from which another thing may be deduced**. It comes ‘from the L. *arguere* “make clear, make known, prove, declare, demonstrate,” from PIE **argu-yo-*, from root **arg-* “to shine, be white, bright, clear” ’, which root is also preserved in the words *argent* (“silvery white”) and *Argentina* (“[river] of silver”).[¹](http://etymonline.com/index.php?search=argue)

Its use in English to mean **a** “**mathematical quantity from which another** … **quantity may be deduced, or on which its calculation depends**” is attested as early as 1386:

> **Argument** (ā·ɹgi*u*měnt). [a. F. *argument* (13th c.), ad. L. *argūment-um*, f. *arguěre* (or refashioning, after this, of OF. *arguement*, f. *arguer*): see A<sub><sup>RGUE</sup></sub>. For use of the L. form, see 3 c.]
>    **2**. *Astr.* and *Math.* The angle, arc, or other mathematical quantity, from which another required quantity may deduced, or on which its calculation depends.
>    *c* **1386** C<sub><sup>HAUCER</sup></sub> *Frankl. T.* 549 Hise othere geeris, As been his centris and hise Argumentz.
>    *c* **1391** — *Astrol.* xliv. 54 To knowe the mene mote and the argumentis of any planete.
>    **1796** H<sub><sup>UTTON</sup></sub> *Math. Dict.* I. 141/2 Annual argument of the moon’s apogee . . is the distance of the sun’s place from the place of the moon’s apogee.
>    **1879** T<sub><sup>HOMPSON</sup></sub> & T<sub><sup>AIT</sup></sub> *Nat. Phil.* I. 1. § 54 An arc of the circle referred to . . is the Argument of the harmonic motion.[²](http://archive.org/stream/oed01arch#page/442/mode/2up)

Answer (score 43):

According to [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/argument#Etymology), the originating Latin word was argumentum, which also means "token". So you can see pretty easily how that term got used in mathematics, most of the texts of which were written in Latin for a long time.

A lot of terms used in mathematics, particularly around functions, naturally spread to programming.

Comment: Wow, +1 for the reference -- the other definitions are helpful as well: subject, contents.

Comment: The word *argumentum* does not mean “token”, not in the sense used in mathematics and computer science (a symbol). In this context, *token* means “evidence” (literally “a showing”), as you might see it in phrases such as “a small *token* of my esteem” or “gave the proposal only *token* support”.

Comment: @MετάEd "Something serving as an indication, proof, or expression of something else" - I don't see how I've used it any other way. I like your answer though. +1 for that.

Comment: @pdr Oh, I'm not criticizing your use of the word. Your answer got my +1. I just see the possibility of confusion because *token* is used a lot in programming in a technical sense meaning “symbol”.

Answer (score 16):

This goes back to celestial mechanics in the pre-calculus days.  Orbits, arcs, chords, sinus, periapsis, and so on.

The term "argument" was used since I don't know how long ago, but it is described in the book "A philosophical and mathematical dictionary, containing an explanation of the terms, and an account of the several subjects, comprised under the heads mathemetics, astronomy, and philosophy both natural and experimental ... also memoirs of the lives and writings of the most eminent authors, both ancient and modern" (that's not the entire title) published in 1815 by Charles Hutton, 1737-1823.

[image: Excerpt defining "argument" from Hutton's book]

(excerpt taken from Google Books)

The "argument" was an angle of some sort. Exactly how that term came to be, I haven't found yet.  At some point in science history, the astronomers realized that the sinus and cosinus, being thus far known only as geometric constructs associated with lines and ellipses, could be thought of as *functions* of the argument.  "Function" was a new concept back in those days.  The notation f(x) had been invented around the early 1700s.

Naturally, astronomers were thinking "sinus of the argument of the periapsis" == "sin(ω)" and later as more functions were found to be useful, any "f(x)" came to be thought of as "function f of argument x".  Even if x wasn't an angle.  Mathematicians of all flavors and stripes came to use such terminology in general.

In the mid 20th Century, it was only natural for computer scientists to borrow the same terminology for their different but similar idea of a function as a subroutine taking any number of input values.

(This is one of those unusual topics that is easier to dig up answers for in a musty university library, than on the internet.)

Comment: *"The "argument" was an angle of some sort."* Oh, are you referring to [the `∠` ("arg") function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(complex_analysis))?

Comment: @Mehrdad and this way we've made a full circle (pun intended) :)